# Dialogflow with user-specific data

Tags: backend, dialogflow-es

Currently I'm using Dialogflow to handle messages from user in a LINE application.
I planned to integrate Dialogflow with custom back-end fulfillment.
The fulfillment should have a database for some user-specific messages (e.g. each user's attributes).

Is there any way to do that in Dialogflow?

Comment: you can find users intent by it's action in your backed and based on this you can give appropriate response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note two things about the solution you figured out:

1. It is platform specific - everything under `originalDetectIntentRequest.playload` comes from the platform that is making the request.
2. If you're using the Actions on Google platform, the `userId` field has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) and will be removed in May 2019.

If you're using Actions on Google, you have a few solutions.

The most straightforward replacement is to use the [`userStorage`](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data) facility provided by Actions on Google. In the most simple case, you can just store the information you want to remember about the user here. If you want or need to use a database instead, then you can generate your own userId for the user and store it in `userStorage` the first time they visit, and retrieve it from there on subsequent visits.

More complicated, but which adds additional features, is to use [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) to associate their connection with another account your system uses, such as [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out.
It's `originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.source.userId`

Comment: Note that this is platform specific and, for one platform, is deprecated. See my answer.